# Flot Bar chart with PHP Variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flot

How to display the values on flot bar chart using my PHP variables.
for example: 
   Instead of saying

```
var data = [    
[0, 11], //London, UK
[1, 15], //New York, USA
[2, 25], //New Delhi, India
[3, 24], //Taipei, Taiwan
[4, 13], //Beijing, China
[5, 18]  //Sydney, AU
  ];
```

I'd like to use my php variables something like:

```
    var data = [    
    [0,  <?php echo '['.($London).']'?>], //London
    [1,  <?php echo '['.($NewYork).']'?>], //New York
    [2, <?php echo '['.($NewDelhi,).']'?>], //New Delhi,
    [3, <?php echo '['.($Taipei).']'?>], //Taipei
   [4,  <?php echo '['.($Beijing).']'?>] //Beijing
  ];
```

Wondering how to echo my variables inside the var data.
Any idea I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are those city variables integers you want to insert?

Comment: Why do you have 2 braces in the 2nd example at the end of each element? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You can pack your php array to json, like

```
// data place

$data = [[0, 11], ...];

// output place

var data = <?php= json_encode($data)?>
```

But in this case you will miss your comments

Comment: Not working with json.Any idea how to print out the php variables inside data =  [..] .Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Vadim Babaev.  I would have said the same thing.

But maybe this could also be useful: look at the Heredoc notation.
It can be really hard to figure out if the ' or " are in php or in javascript.  Both need them; both need good syntax.
Heredoc makes it easy; you will not confuse them.

Your example

```
<?php
// Google "Heredoc notation php" for more information
$javascript_String = <<<JS
var data = [    
  [0, $London],   //London, UK
  [1, $NewYork],  //New York, USA
  [2, $NewDelhi], //New Delhi, India
  [3, $Taipei],   //Taipei, Taiwan
  [4, $Beijing],  //Beijing, China
  [5, $Sydney]    //Sydney, AU
];
JS;
echo '<script>' . $javascript_String . '</script>' ;
?>
```

Comment: @Emmmanuel your code is not working I tried your code not working for me. Any idea please ?

Comment: Heredoc has a few specific requirements.  The bottom "JS;" absolutely has to be written as the first characters of the line.  Do not indent it (No spaces or tabs left of the J); and do not add anything to the right of the ";".  Also, do not add anything to the right of "<<<JS".  Heredoc starts reading from next line.  I presume that's the problem.